# Running tab of values if cell next door is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in ever-expanding rows. Col 1 has 'Fees' and Col 2 has 'Paid'. I wish to be able to find and total together all Fees that have no Paid entered yet. For example:

```
   Fees   Paid
   100    250
    50    125
   100     
   150    200
   100
```

So I'm hoping to be able to correctly calculate that there is 200 outstanding 'Fees', be able to adjust/update when new rows are added/updated, and display that 'outstanding' value within its own cell. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format as a Table (which will allow the references to automatically expand/contract as you add/delete rows.

Then use the `SUMIF` function:

```
=SUMIF(Table1[Paid],"",Table1[Fees])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron, worked a treat!